# how to change the naming of the legend when hue is given in pyplot?

Tags: seaborn

the dataset:

```
index TARGET NAME_INCOME_TYPE   count
0   0   Working                 46924
1   0   Commercial associate    21492
2   0   Pensioner               16879
3   0   State servant           6593
4   0   Student                  9
5   0   Unemployed              6
6   0   Businessman              4
7   0   Maternity leave           1
8   1   Working                 4978
9   1   Commercial associate    1726
10  1   Pensioner               978
11  1   State servant           407
12  1   Unemployed              4
```

the code for chart:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
sns.barplot(x='NAME_INCOME_TYPE',y='percent_rate',hue='TARGET',data=qq,palette='winter',saturation=0.5, hue_order=[0,1])
plt.yticks(size=20)
plt.ylabel(size=20, s = '% rate')
plt.xlabel(size=20, s= 'NAME INCOME TYPE')
plt.xticks(rotation=90,size=20)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

I have specified the hue and it works fine, but the legend has it as "0, 1"
I want to change it to 'yes, no'.

changing the hue_order parameter does not work.

changing the legend does not work.

Answer (score 0):

ok apparently hue order is the right param to use. I just did not swap "0,1" to "1,0".

i coded:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
sns.barplot(x='NAME_INCOME_TYPE',y='percent_rate',hue='TARGET',data=qq,palette='inferno',saturation=0.5,hue_order=['YES', 'NO'])
plt.yticks(size=20)
plt.ylabel(size=20, s = '% rate')
plt.xlabel(size=20, s= 'NAME INCOME TYPE')
plt.xticks(rotation=90,size=20)
plt.title("Income sources of Applicants in terms of loan is repayed or not  in %",size=20)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```